# Including raw_input in a class

Tags: python-2.7, class, if-statement

I have this script:

```
class usr:
  def __init__(self, inp):
    self.inp = inp
    if inp == "abc":
      print 0
      exit()


user_input = usr(raw_input())
if user_input == "123":
  print("1")
else:
  print("No")
```

But, even if I type "123", the output is "No".
In normal circumstances I would put the "abc" statement in an if, but I need to check the input of multiple commands, so I tought that a class was the best choice.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what your question is. Given that you don't implement `usr.__eq__`, how do you expect `user_input == '123'` to be evaluated sensibly? What output are you expecting from this? And why are you using old-style classes (i.e. not inheriting from `object`, despite tagging your question [tag:python-2.7])?

Comment: i do not have objects to inherit from, I suppose

Comment: No, I mean literally from `object`. Read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/54867/3001761

Answer (score 0):

When data doesn't compare like you think it should, the first tool in your toolkit is the print statement. Just add `print user_input` and you'll find its an instance of the `usr` class, not the user input. You stored that in an instance variable called `inp`. As an aside, in pythnon 2, you should inherit from `object` to get a new-style class. You don't need to do that in python 3.

```
class usr(object):
  def __init__(self, inp):
    self.inp = inp
    if inp == "abc":
      print 0
      exit()

user_input = usr(raw_input())
if user_input.inp == "123":
  print("1")
else:
  print("No")
```

If all you want to do is validate the input and not store it, a function is a better option. It can just return the validated string. It can do other prettying up of the data also. In this example, I also strip whitespace from front and back so minor input errors are ignored

```
def usr(inp):
    inp = inp.strip()
    if inp == "abc":
      print 0
      exit()
    return inp

user_input = usr(raw_input())
if user_input == "123":
  print("1")
else:
  print("No")
```